# Javafx pausing my main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have my own thread and when needed I activate GUI with JavaFX that's when my program thread pauses or stop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    loader.init();      
    loader.finish();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My init method

```
    public void init() {
    if(!WebUtil.serverReacheable()) {
        System.out.println("Server is down, please try soon");
        return;
    }
    Preconditions.checkState(!serviceLoader.isShutdown(), "The bootstrap has been bound already!");
    executeServiceLoad();
    serviceLoader.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Initializing application...");
}
```

And where I start the GUI

```
    private void executeServiceLoad() {
    serviceLoader.execute(() ->Application.launch(MaterialLogin.class));
}
```

My Executors

```
private final ExecutorService serviceLoader = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("GameLoadingThread").build());
private final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("GameThread").build());
```

Comment: Your init() method might not be returning when guiMode = true.

Comment: No it's cool, I only used the boolean at the very FX class

Comment: Can you post init code

Comment: @KDM Updated the post

Comment: The launch() method waits till the primaryStage is closed. I guess it is by design. What you may have to do is to run the non-GUI parts in a separate thread.

Comment: Yeah that worked. I created another thread executor just for the GUI

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Thread Executor for my JavaFx Interface thanks to @KDM

```
    private final ExecutorService guiExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("GuiThread").build());
```

Whenever I need call runnable of the other thread I need call Application.runLater() like this

```
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        openDashBoard(response.body());

                    }

                });
```

Comment: Using a executor service just to schedule a single task is pointless. This way you don't have any reuse of the threads of the service and you simply need to shut down the executor in addition to creating the service and scheduling the task. `new Thread(() ->Application.launch(MaterialLogin.class)).start()` has the same result as `ExecutorService guiExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); guiExecutor.submit(() ->Application.launch(MaterialLogin.class)); guiExecutor.shutdown();`